# "Invalid Subject" when making an assertion with Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

Im trying to make some assertions in one of my React component with Cypress, but im getting the following error:

[image: Error]

The output of the console.log is

[image]

And the code that i'm trying to use is

```
cy.getByDataTestAttribute("redeem-product-button").then(($buttons) => {
      console.log($buttons);
      $buttons.each(($button) => {
        cy.wrap($button).should("not.be.disabled");
      });

      // cy.wrap($buttons[0]).click();

      // $buttons.each(($button) => {
      //   cy.wrap($button).should("have.  e 2wrq2", "disabled");
      // });
    });

// commands.ts

Cypress.Commands.add("getByDataTestAttribute", (dataTestAttribute, ...args) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy=${dataTestAttribute}]`, ...args);
});

// button.tsx

<Button
        data-cy="redeem-product-button"
        colorScheme={"brand.default"}
        bg={ableToRedeem ? "brand.default" : "neutrals.500"}
        _hover={{ bg: ableToRedeem ? "brand.default" : "neutrals.600" }}
        disabled={redeemProductState.loading || !ableToRedeem}
        padding="24px"
        borderRadius={"16px"}
        marginTop="16px"
        width="100%"
        onClick={() => redeemProduct(id, cost)}
        color={ableToRedeem ? "white" : "brand.900"}
      > // ...
```

Also, i was using this custom command in other tests in the same file and im not having any trouble with that. But i tried also with

```
cy.get('[data-cy="redeem-product-button"]')
```

Comment: It looks like a mixture of sync/async code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly do like this:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="redeem-product-button"]').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).should('not.be.disabled')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Any clues as to why it doesn't work the way I tried?

Comment: You have to instead of `$buttons.each(($button) => {` use `cy.wrap($buttons).each(($button) => {`